# Delete image from folder "Picture" that actually works nowdays?

Tags: android, android-studio

Does anyone know how to delete an image from gallery, most specifically from folder "Picture" that ACTUALLY works this days? I've tried literally EVERYTHING available here on this site and even from others, but everything is too old and none of them seems to work anymore... My problem is that I have a function on my app to rotate an image selected from the gallery to send as a chat msg. I have to use this function to fix the bug with Samsung devices that doesn't recognize portrait images and put them as landscape. But the problem with this function is that it creates another image on user's gallery, so I want to delete that duplicated file after the app upload it to Firebase. But I just can't do it! I tried everything and none of them was capable to delete the damn file! Please someone give something up to this date please...

Below is my sniped code...

Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_CODE);
```

On ActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        hideBottomSheet();
        displayLoadingBar();

        Uri photoUri = data.getData();
        String imagePath = PathUtil.getRealPathFromURI(ChatActivity.this, photoUri);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        imageUri = rotatedImage(bitmap, imagePath);

        uploadFile(imageUri, imageStorageReference);

    }
}
```

Rotate Image function:

```
    public Uri rotatedImage(Bitmap bitmap, String photoPath) {
        ExifInterface exifInterface = null;
        try {
            exifInterface = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 
                          ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(270);
                break;
            default:
        }

        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 
                               bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), rotatedBitmap, 
                      null, null);

        return Uri.parse(path);
   }
```

As you can see when I get the path inside the rotate function is when the duplicated image is being created, but I don't know how to get the path from a bitmap without creating a new one physically in storage... If you know, that could be a solution as well... But if that is not possible, what I would like is to delete that second image after calling the "uploadFile" function inside the "activityResult". Please help me!!!

Comment: If you do not want the image to be in the `MediaStore`, you might consider not putting it there in the first place. For example, you could save your rotated image in a file in `getCacheDir()` and use `FileProvider` to get a `Uri` for that file.

Comment: I don't know how to implement that... How am I gonna associate the new rotatedBitmap with the getCacheDir() function? Can you show me with the code please?

Comment: There are instructions in [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) and [elsewhere in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing).

Comment: Dude I tried to follow the documentation you sent me but I can't get it to work, no matter what I do the Uri always comes back null... I'm tired... I've spent almost a month on this problem already. Please if you know how to solve this, show me the code please...

Comment: Never mind, just found a solution! I'm gonna post it as an answer, in case someone else has the same problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after searching the hell and back, and with a tip from CommonsWare in the comments above I finally managed to come up with a solution for my problem. So in case someone else landed here with the same problem. This is what worked for me.

I replaced this line of code inside of rotatedImage function:

```
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), rotatedBitmap, null, null);
return Uri.parse(path);
```

for this:

```
byte[] bitmapData = bytes.toByteArray();

try {
    File tempFile = createImageFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    fos.write(bitmapData);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();

    Uri newUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ChatActivity.this, "com.yourapp.fileprovider", tempFile);

    return newUri;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
```

Here is the createImageFile function:

```
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
    );

    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    return  image;
}
```